# Any way to wrap code to detect App pool crashs IIS 7 MVC 3.0

Tags: c#, iis-7

I have an MVC 3.0 application that when deployed  crashs the app pool every time a certain page is run.

This page is not doing anything different to any of  the other pages, basically
Grabs a database record and  presents the information using a view.

I have not been able to figure out why it crashes causing the app pool to shut down  and shutting down the entire site.
I have install ELMAH log tracking and have wrapped a base controller but as  the app pool crashes no logs get written to ELMAH

I have tried to catch all unmanaged exceptions  using this method
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911816  however the app pool still crashs and  I am no closer  to finding a solution.

None of the code is unmanaged so I am not sure why this is happening except for  calls to the database that could be  failing but see no errors in the database logs.
I am using  DynamicMethod to generate IL code to  map to the database structure to my models but the same implementation works for every other model and  the broken call works ok on my dev machine.

**Question 1** If this IL generated code fails should the exception still be caught in the standard request error handling?

Event logs are  cryptic and next to useless.

```
Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP      000007FEFA352648 (000007FEFA350000) with exit code 80131506.
```

DebugDiag for 64 bit windows  only allows me to  analyze dump files and I am unable to attach it to app pool or IIS process.

Application runs perfectly in Debug and release mode in VS2010.

**Question 2** I am developing on 32 bit  but deploying to 64 bit.  Is there any scenario where  something works fine in 32 bit  but fails in a 64 bit environment?

**Question 3** I am not sure  what other logging or approach  I can do to find this problem.
Is there any other logging or code I can wrap my request with to try and track the issue.

I am pretty sure it must be a crash in the Dynamic method code, so if  anyone can answer Question1 then that will really help

Comment: I assume i have a similar problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123731/random-session-timeout-in-asp-net-mvc3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok The problem was with the DynamicMethod  generate IL code was failing.

If the field type and database type did not match up it crashed the entire app-pool

Any type mismatches should of been found on the development server however the 
The issue was a database type of int and  field type of Decimal 
did not break on the 32 bit dev machines but broke on the 64 bit deploy server.

Generating IL Code to a dll and  running  PEVerify showed the problem.

Question 1.   No, 
Question 2.   In this situation yes 
Question 3.   PEVerify,     if you are  generating IL code always run it through PEVerify.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is a fatal CLR crash.

1) No

2) You need to build for appropriate runtime.

3) Without sharing information on what you do in the code and what unmanaged resources you use, it is impossible to help any further.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the response,  I Don't have any unmanaged code apart from what would be in 3rd party DLL's. The only one I could think of that could be causing the problem IS NPGSQL  the postgres database provider I am using however I have used this DLL in production on several sites with no problems. 
With the answer NO to question 1 I think that must be  the culprit.

Comment: NPGSQL  it is the data provider for my postgres database.

Comment: @Aliostad so ILGenerator  is unmanaged and can throw exceptions that crash the appserver?

Comment: So it is a CLR bug? I really don't think so :) I think the query might bring back byte data or something and corrupt the heap and bang. There seems to be something in **that query**.

Comment: @Aliostad Sorry that was  a question not a statement about ILGenerator, what I am asking is that If I have badly written ILGenerator code in my DynamicMethod and it fails, can it crash the app-pool. As the app-pool is crashing due to unhandled exceptions. You answered No to question 1 that Dynamic methods would not be caught by standard request error handlers. So could this be why its causing the crash?  I am unsure based on you last comment and am just trying to figure out what area of the application to focus on to find the error