# How to increase Session timeout in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 (Razor) Application and I am faced with frequent session timeouts.
Is there a way to increase the value of the session?

Answer (score 36):

You're not providing enough details, such as your configuration, description of the problem etc.

What's happening more exactly? This article may help:
[Random Session Timeout in ASP.NET MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123731/random-session-timeout-in-asp-net-mvc3)
If not, you could use a configuration like this in your `web.config` file :

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" />
  </system.web>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Here the session timeout is being set to 30 minutes, for example.

Answer (score 13):

In web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20"/>
```

You have to change the value of `timeout` attribute.