# Maintain session for one hour in MVC 3 ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Every time I log in for first time my application session is null
how to maintain session for one hour or day?
Need suggestion please waiting for the answer..

Comment: You might be waiting a while, with a question like that.

Comment: Here is a way to increase the session time out in MVC3 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519715/how-increase-session-time-out-in-mvc3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintains session timeouts add the following entry in web.config

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <sessionState 
        mode="InProc"
        cookieless="true"
        timeout="30" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The above code example sets the timeout session attribute to 30 minutes in the Web.config file.

Comment: Its probably a good thing that your answer has the wrong timeout value, please don't change it. It gives OP a chance to understand what it does

Comment: Thanks Jatin patil its Working Fine ...

Comment: Dont Use  cookieless="true" because the url is changing...thanks